# Install.packages("ggplot2") installing older version (1.0.0)

Tags: r, r-package, revolution-r

So I installed an old version of `ggplot2` with `install_version` from `devtools` (0.9.1 or something) to see how it worked - over the previously installed 2.0.0 version by the way. I then upgraded the version and it surprisingly gave me version 1.0.0, not the current 2.0.0.

Now when I do an `install.packages("ggplot2")` I get the same 1.0.0. Also selecting "`Check for package upgrades..`" item from the Rstudio menu it tells me "All packages up to date".

What gives? Isn't the newest version of `ggplot` now 2.0.0? Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.9.1  ggplot2_1.0.0   dplyr_0.4.3     shiny_0.12.2    RevoUtils_7.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.2      magrittr_1.5     MASS_7.3-43      munsell_0.4.2    colorspace_1.2-6
 [6] xtable_1.8-0     R6_2.1.1         stringr_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.2     
[11] parallel_3.2.2   grid_3.2.2       gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        htmltools_0.2.6 
[16] assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.8     reshape2_1.4.1   memoise_0.2.1    mime_0.4        
[21] stringi_1.0-1    scales_0.3.0     jsonlite_0.9.19  httpuv_1.3.3     proto_0.3-10    
>
```

Here are the repositories it is seeing:

```
> AP <- available.packages() 
> apdf <- data.frame(AP)
> unique(apdf$Repository)
[1] http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2014-12-01/src/contrib
[2] http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib                     
2 Levels: http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2014-12-01/src/contrib ...
>
```

## Update:

Thanks to Dirk, I see what happened. Looks like installing RRO package reset my CRAN repository. I can also sort of see why that had to be, although maybe I should have got a warning about it. From this blog entry I see how to fix it too. http://www.r-bloggers.com/permanently-setting-the-cran-repository/

Comment: in install.packages(c("ggplot2")) is the c a typo?

Comment: Uh, yeah, I guess I don't need it. Was thinking it wanted a list. That is what I type normally though.

Comment: The typo does not matter; your list of repositories might and you do not show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
 AP <- available.packages()     # possibly with repo options
```

and examine the result set.

That is what *your* R session knows about packages, and it is a function of

- the R version; you generally want the newest series (and you have 3.2.*)
- the repos you select (which you did not show)

*Edit:* I typically use `options("repos")` to check which repositories I have, and I tend to control that from `Rprofile.site`. But you seem to have RevoR and I do not know how/if that interacts.

Comment: Done, see above. Is there a command to see what repositories it searches?

Comment: Ok, there is no ggplot2 2.0.0 in that list. How did that happen? I installed some Revolution stuff last night. That is probably related.

Comment: Yes I see what happened now and will have a talk with the Revo people why this is :). Thanks.

Comment: And I see how to fix it.